# Why can't SBT find findbugs?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, sbt, findbugs

I've got a project with a dependency on Google findbugs. When I run it from the SBT console, I get the following:

```
[info] Resolving com.google.code.findbugs#jsr305;1.3.+ ...
[warn]  module not found: com.google.code.findbugs#jsr305;1.3.+
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/me/.ivy2/local/com.google.code.findbugs/jsr305/[revision]/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/[revision]/jsr305-[revision].pom
[warn]   [3.0.1, 3.0.0, 2.0.3, 2.0.2]
[warn] ==== sbt-releases-repo: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.google.code.findbugs/jsr305/[revision]/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugins-repo: tried
[warn]   http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.google.code.findbugs/jsr305/[revision]/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== maven-central: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/[revision]/jsr305-[revision].pom
[warn]   [3.0.1, 3.0.0, 2.0.3, 2.0.2]
[warn] ==== scalaz-bintray: tried
[warn] ==== Sonatype OSS Snapshots: tried
[warn]   http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/[revision]/jsr305-[revision].pom
[warn] ==== scalaz-bintray: tried
[warn]   http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/[revision]/jsr305-[revision].pom
[warn] ==== LocalIvy: tried
[warn] ==== Sonatype OSS Snapshots: tried
[warn]   http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/[revision]/jsr305-[revision].pom
```

and then, finally:

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.google.code.findbugs#jsr305;1.3.+: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.+
```

In the Libraries GUI in Intellij, I see the following:

[image]

What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're requesting 1.3.x, that is not available, 3.0.x is what is available. Change your build to request the correct version

Comment: [Nope, it's not that](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/)

Comment: Also, it's a dependency of another library which I'm using, so I can't change it, or can I?

Comment: It is exactly that, see https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/maven-metadata.xml -- add an explicit dependency and you will be fine

Comment: Ah I see. How can I update it though, given it's a dependency of a dependency (and hence not under my control)?

Comment: Depend on it yourself

Comment: Sorry, how does that work exactly? I have included a dependency on the newer version within my project, but that doesn't satisfy the dependency of the imported library.

Comment: If including it yourself doesn't satisfy, `excludeAll` the bad transitive